# protobuf-net handling for negative ints

Tags: protobuf-net

Using protobuf-net, is it possible to leverage the Zigzag encoding for negative ints?

When attempting to serialize object properties that have negative values, protobuf-net falls back to fixed32/fixed64 encoding instead of the efficient Zigzag encoding.

E.g.

```
[ProtoContract]
internal class TestPoint
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    internal long Value;
}

var p = new TestPoint() { Value = -150 };
```

Serializes to 11 bytes.

```
var p = new TestPoint() { Value = 150 };
```

Serializes to 3 bytes.

From ProtoWriter.cs:

```
            case WireType.Variant:
                if (value >= 0)
                {
                    WriteUInt64Variant((ulong)value, writer);
                    writer.wireType = WireType.None;
                }
                else
                {
                    DemandSpace(10, writer);
                    ...
```

Is there a way to decorate a member in a serialized class to use the WireType.SignedVariant? Couldnt find any way to do this in the source code.

Otherwise, using protobuf for negative numbers defeats the purpose of an otherwise excellent wire compression.

Please assist!

Regards,
Mike

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41692470/protobuf-net-cant-send-negative-
number#
sir,I need your help that I have a same question?

Answer (score 2):

Sure; protobuf has a few different encodings; what you want here is zig-zag encoding:

```
[ProtoMember(1, DataFormat = DataFormat.ZigZag)]
```

which has the xml-comment in protobuf-net:

```
/// <summary>
/// When applied to signed integer-based data (including Decimal), this
/// indicates that zigzag variant encoding will be used. This means that values
/// with small magnitude (regardless of sign) take a small amount
/// of space to encode.
/// </summary>
ZigZag
```

Comment: At times my data is smashed into a `uint64_t` but I know that ZigZag would be better, but your DataFormat comment mentioned that it applies to 'signed' integers. Does it _only_apply to signed and will not work on unsigned at all? Or is it agnostic?

Comment: @Marius zigzag is designed to avoid negative integers from always taking 10 bytes; nothing more, nothing less; if you're using uint64_t  (`ulong` in C# terms), then you don't really need zigzag - the choice is simply "varint" vs "fixed"; fixed will always take 8 bytes; varint will take variable size between 1 and 10 bytes depending on magnitude; if you're only occasionally using the full 64-bit scale, then varint sounds ideal, and *is the default*