# protobuf-net can't send Negative number

Tags: protobuf-net

```
    [Required]
    [DefaultValue(-1)]

    public int MvcUserId { get; set; }
```

when I set MvcUserId =-1;
but I will get MvcUserId =0;
if i use json serlize the object ,everything will be ok.

Comment: `[DefaultValue(-1)]` means that `MvcUserId` has a default value of -1 so that specific value does not need to be sent over the wire.   That means you need to set it in your constructor.  See [DefaultValue properties deserialization](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16650231/3744182).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DefaultValue properties deserialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649924/defaultvalue-properties-deserialization)

Comment: @dbc DefaultValue only for Entity Framework, No matter protobuf-NET.

Answer (score 0):

You need to *actually apply the default*:

```
[Required]
[DefaultValue(-1)]
public int MvcUserId { get; set; } = -1;
```

Without that protobuf-net ignores the value on send (because it is the default), and on receive there is *nothing to process*. protobuf-net assumes that **your code** correctly applies the defaults.